# Script sometimes logs in a website but fails most of the times

Tags: vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11, queryselector

I've created a vba script using Internet Explorer to log in a website using my credentials. The thing is the script sometimes works flawlessly but most of the times it fails while hitting the `sign in` button, meaning gets stuck there.

```
Sub SignIn()
    Const Url$ = "https://member.angieslist.com/app/search?categoryName=Plumbing&isMisspelling=false&query=Plumbing&categorySearchType=legacy&category=107"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim oPass As Object, oMail As Object, oButton As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document

        With HTML
            Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .querySelectorAll("#login--login-email").Length > 0
            Set oMail = .querySelector("#login--login-email")
            oMail.Focus
            oMail.innerText = "useremail"

            Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .querySelectorAll("#login--login-password").Length > 0
            Set oPass = .querySelector("#login--login-password")
            oPass.Focus
            oPass.innerText = "password"

            Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .querySelectorAll("#login--login-button").Length > 0
            Set oButton = .querySelector("#login--login-button")
            oButton.Focus
            oButton.Click 'It gets here stuck most of the times
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

***How can I log in that site without fail?***

Comment: Do you meet any error? whether the account is validated? please try to use F12 developer tools to check it (using the console tools to check whether it contains some Javascript error, and use the Network tools to check the request result).

Answer (score 0):

This *MIGHT* work...50/50 shot.

```
  Sub SignIn()
Const Url$ = "https://member.angieslist.com/app/search?categoryName=Plumbing&isMisspelling=false&query=Plumbing&categorySearchType=legacy&category=107"
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim oPass As Object, oMail As Object, objElement As Object, objCollection As Object

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate Url
    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Set HTML = .document

    With HTML
        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .querySelectorAll("#login--login-email").Length > 0
        Set oMail = .querySelector("#login--login-email")
        oMail.Focus
        oMail.innerText = "useremail"

        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .querySelectorAll("#login--login-password").Length > 0
        Set oPass = .querySelector("#login--login-password")
        oPass.Focus
        oPass.innerText = "password"

        Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block btn-flat")
        ElementCol.Item(0).Click
    End With
End With
```

End Sub